# Firestore Rules OK with Test Emulator but "Insufficient Permission" in prod

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have security rules that checks:

1. The users is connected
2. He is writing on its "own" node (`users/{userId}`)
3. The documents is written in an authorized collections ("contacts", "interactions" or "events")
4. The document has been generated with a structure compatible with the user database (the version of the document -- field `v` -- is the same as the version of the user database -- field `version` of the userDoc)

Concerning the point 4, if the userDoc does not exist yet or does not have a version field, then the new document should be accepted *(it's the first document of a new user, and a cloud function will use it's `v` field to create and initialize the `version` field of the userDoc)*

**The issue is: the rules do not work on prod for the 1st document (when the userDoc does not exists), but they work when I test them with the test tool!** (I receive the error `Missing or insufficient permissions.`)

In my rules, I have the following function that check for point 4:

```
        function resourceVersionIsCompatible(resourceVersion) {
          let userDoc = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId));
          let serverVersion = userDoc != null && 'version' in userDoc.data ? int(string(userDoc.data.version).split('\\.')[0]) : 0;
          return (serverVersion == 0) || (resourceVersion == serverVersion);          
        }
```

If I replace `userDoc != null` by `false`, then it works well (I can create the first document. And then I can restore the normal rules to create the subsequent documents with working version check).
**So it seems the issue is that a non existant document returns something else than null when in prod.** *When testing with the "rules tester", it correctly returns `null`, that's why it works correctly in tester.*

The complete rules are below:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {

  match /databases/{database}/documents {

        // Everything is disallowed if not specifically allowed after
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }

    match /users/{userId} {

      allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow write: if false;

      match /{collection}/{documentId} {

        function resourceIsValid(resourceVersion) {
          return resourceVersion <= 2 && {
            'version-1': (collection == 'interactions' || collection == 'contacts'),
            'version-2': (collection == 'events' || collection == 'contacts')
          }['version-' + string(resourceVersion)];
        }

        function resourceVersionIsCompatible(resourceVersion) {
          let userDoc = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId));
          let serverVersion = userDoc != null && 'version' in userDoc.data ? int(string(userDoc.data.version).split('\\.')[0]) : 0;
          // We allow the request if the resourceVersion is the same major than the serverVersion
          // of if there is no serverVersion (then a cloud function will initiate it based on the doc version)
          return (serverVersion == 0) || (resourceVersion == serverVersion);          
        }

        function creationAllowed() {
            let resourceVersionMajor = 'v' in request.resource.data ? int(string(request.resource.data.v).split('\\.')[0]) : 1;
          return request.auth.uid == userId
            && resourceIsValid(resourceVersionMajor)
            && resourceVersionIsCompatible(resourceVersionMajor);
        }

        allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
        allow delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
        allow create, update: if creationAllowed();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit : note that in the "rules monitoring" panel, I do not have any "access forbidden" but only few "errors" (and a lot of "success"). But since the debug env do not trigger any error, I do not know how I can solve this errors :(

Comment: Seems like a bug that you have to contact firebase support with:
https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact

Comment: I contacted Firebase, but I'm not sure we are aligned concerning the urgency :p they told me to do a "exists()" request before every "get()" request, even if it doubles the database requests (and the price).